# Keep C++ Program to be always running

Tags: c++, windows, sendinput

I have C++ program written for Windows, which uses SendInput() to emulate keyboard keys. The program works and sends space key, which works fine in Icy Tower (Game) and the character keeps on jumping. However when I tried it with game like Counter Strike it didn't jump and when I tried pressing alt+tab to switch quickly between my program and the game I found the game to jump for once and the SendInput() makes it's way. So my guess is that when the program is in the background it doesn't send the keys to the game, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: SendKeys() emulates virtual keys, most games use DirectX or other APIs to get input, which in general get data from a level of the input processing stack more lower than the level where virtual keys are generated. As far I know, DirectInput works with hardware keys, which are lower than virtual keys. That's why your emulated keys are not handled by Counter Strike

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx.